# How can I downgrade cuDNN from v8.0 to v6.0 in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

This follows on from this question: [How to downgrade Cuda and cuDNN Version in Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791108/how-to-downgrade-cuda-and-cudnn-version-in-google-colab)

I've followed the instructions and have first downgraded Cuda 10.0 to Cuda 8.0.  I've then downloaded cuDNN v6.0 to my local drive and uploaded to my Google Drive which I have mounted. I then install with the following code:

!dpkg -i "~/Downloads/libcudnn6_6.0.21-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb"

!ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.6*

I get a message in the log as follows:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ideep4py/lib/libmkldnn.so.0 is not a symbolic link
```

It does appear to have been installed:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        18 Apr 12  2017 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.6 -> libcudnn.so.6.0.21
```

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 154322864 Apr 12  2017 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.6.0.21

When I check where cuDNN is installed I get:

```
cudnn: /usr/include/cudnn.h
```

### Checking the version I get:

#define CUDNN_VERSION (CUDNN_MAJOR * 1000 + CUDNN_MINOR * 100 + CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL)

#include "driver_types.h"

However, when I try to use my model I receive:

```
no CUDA-capable device is detected
```

I'm confused.  Have I installed the correct version of cuDNN properly?

Comment: `libmkldnn` has nothing to do with CUDNN

Comment: ok, so I can ignore this message?  Where should cuDNN be installed?