# downgrade tensorflow GPU from v2.8 to v2.7 in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I have some models I trained using TF and have been using for awhile now but since V2.8 came out I am having issues with the models based in MobileNetV3 (large and small), I [posted the issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/55432) on the tensor-flow git and am waiting for a solution. In the mean time I wan to make some predictions on colab using V2.7 instead of 2.8. I know this involves installing CUDA and and cuDNN. I am really in experienced at this level and setting up TF. does anyone know how to proceed with this? I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791108/how-to-downgrade-cuda-and-cudnn-version-in-google-colab) but was hoping for a less intensive solution. like can I 'flash' an old colab machine that has 2.7 setup?

as a side note, shouldn't colab have options like this? the main reason I am using colab is that I can run my code anywhere and that it is repeatable.

also I can install and run my code for V2.7 for the CPU version but I want to run on the GPU.

thanks for your help!

---

edit: sorry I did a poor job at explaining what I already tried. I have tired using pip

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==2.7.*
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.7.*
```

but I get this error

```
UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
```

I have also pip uninstalled keras, TF and TF-GPU before installing and I get the same error. yes I restart the runtime as well. someone mentioned that conda tried to install everything when installing TF, is this a possible solution?

Comment: to me, pip install work fine, `!pip install tensorflow==2.7.0` then restart runtime, the version down to 2.7 and the GPU is available

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried that already and I get an error message when using GPU runtime to predict (see my edit). did you try this recently? have you tried predicting using a CNN?

Comment: @Phillip Maire, The Reason of getting this error is due to the mismatch of the version of the CUDA and cuDNN with your Tensorflow version or out of memory. For more details you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53698035/). To use google colab, you just follow the steps mentioned by CuCaRot and it's working for me. Please let me know incase of any queries. Thanks!